# Trigger effect after changing src attribute of img tag

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous, setattribute

Im using this code to change the src attribute of an image tag (using prototype and scriptaculous):

```
new Effect.Fade("images",{afterFinish:
function()
{
    $("detail").setAttribute("src", "img/02.jpg");
    new Effect.Appear("images",{duration:0.8});
}
});
```

Where "images" is the container (a div) and "detail" is the img tag
The result is the current image fades, appears and then the new image suddenly shows.
My question is, how can i check the new image is fully loaded by the browser to trigger the Effect.Appear after?
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images have an `onload` event you can hook up to:

```
$("detail").onload = function() 
 { do_stuff(); }  // Remember to do this BEFORE changing the src
```

In my experience, it is a bit flaky sometimes (at times doesn't seem to get executed). It would be better to pre-load the image and allow this effect only after the full document has loaded (`onload` instead of `dom:load` or `ready`).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
new Effect.Appear("images",{duration:0.8});
```

with

```
Event.observe("detail", 'load', function() {
    new Effect.Appear("images",{duration:0.8});
    Event.stopObserving('detail', 'load'); 
});
```

To tell the user that you are loading the image, you could set a css background to the image, with a spinnging circle or whatever suits.